# How to Integrate a Cloud Function Into a Jenkins File?

Tags: python, jenkins, google-cloud-platform, jenkins-pipeline, google-cloud-storage

I have written a cloud function in GCP, which inserts data into BigQuery when a file is uploaded to my GCS Bucket, but I am wondering how to integrate this into a Jenkins file/pipeline.

I have checked the Jenkins documentation, but I am unclear on how to actually integrate my cloud function into Jenkins.

This is my cloud function code:

```
def csv_in_gcs_to_table(event, context):

    from google.cloud import bigquery

    client = bigquery.Client()

    bucket_name = "bucket_name"
    object_name = event['name']
    table_id = "project_id.dataset_name.table_name"

    schema = [
        bigquery.SchemaField('col1', 'string'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('col2', 'string'),
    ]

    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    job_config.schema = schema
    job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV
    job_config.write_disposition = bigquery.WriteDisposition().WRITE_APPEND
    job_config.skip_leading_rows = 1

    uri = "gs://{}/{}".format(bucket_name, object_name)

    load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(uri,
                                          table_id,
                                          job_config=job_config)
    load_job.result()
```

Also, does the trigger code need to be added to the Jenkins file too?

Comment: Can you refer to this [Link1](https://medium.com/@alekhyachowdhury/automating-gcp-cloud-function-testing-using-jenkins-4c7b8fe5ed5) and [Link2](https://plugins.jenkins.io/google-storage-plugin/)

Comment: Do you want to deploy your function?

Comment: I have checked out those docs, and I am not sure where to begin.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes, I am wanting to deploy my function, too, using Jenkins as the orchestration tool, but I am not sure how to do this with my current code. Is there an example? Thanks.

Comment: All I am wanting to know is how to write my Jenkins file to deploy this Cloud Function.

Comment: Does it help? https://medium.com/@alekhyachowdhury/automating-gcp-cloud-function-testing-using-jenkins-4c7b8fe5ed5

Comment: Hi - that does help, thank you. Though, as the tutorial is using pub/sub - how would I accomplish it for a Cloud Storage trigger?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I have written a Jenkins pipeline now, and now I am wondering, how do I get it to execute my code files in GCP? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75324541/how-to-i-get-my-jenkins-pipeline-to-execute-my-code-in-gcp-cloud-functions