# How to I get my Jenkins pipeline to execute my code in GCP Cloud Functions?

Tags: python, jenkins, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, jenkins-pipeline

New to Jenkins here, and I have written the following Jenkins pipeline to execute my Cloud Function, which is in GCP, but I am unsure what I need to do in order to execute my code files in GCP.

```
    agent any

    stages {

        stage('Build') {

            steps {

                sh 'gcloud config set account yyyy@yyyy.iam.gserviceaccount.com'

                sh '''
gcloud functions deploy helloWorld --region=us-central1 --runtime nodejs8 --trigger-http --project yyyy \

                '''

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Do I need to add something that defines the location of my code or what? I am unsure.

My code files are in my GCP Cloud Function, so how do I get my Jenkins pipeline to execute those files?

Please help.

I have tried to look at the Jenkins documentation, but I am unclear on what I need to add to my pipeline, so I can execute my code files.

Comment: It's important to be clear and sharp about the words. Execute a functions (invoke it) is different to deploy it. Usually, with Jenkins you deploy a funcitons, you don't invoke them. But you also could invoke them. That's why I'm a bit lost. In addition, that sentence `My code files are in my GCP Cloud Function, so how do I get my Jenkins pipeline to execute those files?` is totally blurry. Your code is not in your Cloud Functions, it is in your repository, and then you deploy that files on Cloud Functions, you don't execute the files. Or you could do something different. Please clarify!

Comment: OK - I understand what you are saying, but where is my repository?

Comment: I have created my Cloud Function in GCP, and added my code; now, I want to use Jenkins to deploy my function, so how do I do that?

Comment: Your code is correct. You have to be aware that the command that you run (gcloud) takes the source file in the current directory. use the `--source` parameter to define a sub directory to allow gcloud to upload the correct file to deploy. Jenkins is not so different as your local environment, it's just automated.

Comment: Right...I see. Thanks for the feedback - it has really helped me. Also, for the ```--source``` parameter, do I need to create a new sub directory or add the URL of where my files are in GCP Cloud Functions?

Comment: YOU DO NOT HAVE files in Cloud Functions. You have your directory with source file, but not mix all the things. You simply have to set in the --source parameter the root path of your files to deploy on Cloud Functions. It's only local file, no remote files.